# Error with search in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, call

I add this method in my adapter :

```
public  void filterlist(List<ListItem> newlist){
    listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    listItems.addAll(newlist);
    notifyDataSetChanged(); }
}
```

And I use this code in MainActivity to Filter the list put I can not call the **filterlist()** method

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //Do some magic
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            //Do some magic
            String item = newText.toLowerCase();
            List<ListItem> newlist = new ArrayList<>();
            for (ListItem name:listItems){
                if (name.getDoname().toLowerCase().contains(newText)){newlist.add(name);}
            }

            // the is problem in this line

            adapter.filterlist(newlist); 
            return true;
        }
    }
```

there is a problem in this line  `adapter.filterlist(newlist);`

I cannot call the method **filterlist** appear to me with red color why?

Comment: Check if **adapter** is instance of your custom adapter.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions in this code? if yes, then paste logcat.

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'filterlist(java.util.List<com.example.peter.bloodonation.RecycleView.ListItem>)'

Comment: put your all code of MainActivity and Adapter.

Comment: Thank you the problem was in initialzation my adapter

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
listItems = new ArrayList<>();
listItems.addAll(newlist);
```

Do below:

```
listItems.clear();
listItems.addAll(newlist);
```

This is because instead of creating the new instance of the list, modify the existing list instance for the adapter to notify the changes,

Answer (score 0):

Update list in the Adapter is look like this,

```
 public void updateList(ArrayList<Currency> temp) {
            this.mCurrencyList = temp;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

And you have to apply this in your search box field.
You applied on Query change listener and i implemented addTextChangeListener

```
searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    ArrayList<Currency> temp = new ArrayList();
    for (Currency d : mCurrencyList) {
    if (d.getCode().toLowerCase().contains(s.toString().toLowerCase())) {
    temp.add(d);
                }
                 }
    mSelectCurrencyAdapter.updateList(temp);
                    }
    });
```

Most Important thing is that you applied with search view  and i applied with Edit Text view.

But I think that's works fine for search view also.